# Would the order of the Avatar cycle change after Korra started a new cycle?

Tags: avatar-the-last-airbender, the-legend-of-korra

So the avatar cycle goes in the order of air, water, earth, fire and since Korra started a new cycle does that mean the order of the cycle will change?

Answer (score -1):

Since the original order was how Wan learned the elements I think the new order will be how Korra learned them which I think is, Water, Fire, Earth then Air.

Comment: I've edited this answer so it reads as an actual answer rather than a stab in the dark. This is a question and answer site and so answers should be used to answer the question; this does that but was original written more as a comment than an answer. It seems like a reasonable theory so keep it as an answer and be confident in it! Though I would say you should [edit] this to try and provide some evidence to back it up beyond what you have here.

Comment: Didn't episode 1 start with Korra just finishing her **Firebending** training before moving to Republic City to learn Airbending?

Comment: Didnt Wan learn fire first ?

Answer (score -2):

That hasn’t been any official statements of if the order of the avatar cycle will be altered after Korra, but in my opinion that will not be altered so the next avatar would be an earth bender.

To support my opinion, I think the earth kingdom even though was very present during TLOK specially on books 3 and 4, still needs a more popular avatar. As to a series focused on that would be very interesting to explore the earth kingdom after the effects of kuvira on book 4.